# Iframe SandBox is blocking embed object

Tags: iframe, sandbox

Hy here is a examle
[Example](http://www.ufilme.ro/index/cereri/0-11) 
Why when i use

```
<IFRAME sandbox="allow-forms allow-scripts" SRC="http://roshare.info/embedx-xcnvxz71l8fb-699x380.html" FRAMEBORDER=0 MARGINWIDTH=0 MARGINHEIGHT=0 SCROLLING=NO WIDTH=699 HEIGHT=400></IFRAME>
```

sandbox i dont see the player .. i want to use sandbox just to block pop-ups but looks like if i use it i dont see the player 
is there any `allow-objects` ?

I have also a no sandbox example on that page and it works ..

Answer (score 4):

You're correct. The sandbox will block plugin content inside the frame. Unlike other aspects of the sandbox, there is no mechanism for enabling plugins inside a sandboxed `iframe`. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/#granular-control-over-capabilities has more detail if you're curious.

Comment: So how would one embed an audio file into a page that is loaded via iframe? Do i really have to send the audio file's src to the parent which then would have to play it?