# jsfiddle - embed svg is not supported in jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I've built a visualisation component library using `javascript` and `jquery`. In a component called Flags, I am getting `svg` document as repsonse in `jquery's ajax` call.

First I tried to append that `svg` document with `dataType:xml` in `jquery ajax()` and the below code:

```
var container = $(document.createElement("div"));                        
var importedSVGRootElement = document.importNode(this.flag.documentElement, true);            
container.append(importedSVGRootElement);
```

This works fine in Chrome and on jsfiddle as well. Later I changed it to `embed` tag as below to maintain the sequence of flags as per my requirements.

```
var stampDiv = $(document.createElement("embed")).attr("src", this.flag + '?apikey=' +     Data.apiKey).attr("type", "image/svg+xml");        
    container.append(flagDiv);
```

This was also working fine in Chrome and on jsfiddle. But 2 days ago it stopped working on jsfiddle. I could not identify the issue so I finally changed it to `img` tag as below:

```
var stampDiv = $(document.createElement("img")).attr("src", this.flag+ '?apikey=' + Data.apiKey); 
        container.append(flagDiv);
```

`svg` as `img` works in all three major browsers and on jsfiddle as well. My question is why `embed src=svg` stopped workding on jsfiddle ??? I couldn't modify `svg` document in case of it's displayed as `img` on browser. After appending the `svg` I need to edit it.

**Update:**
JSFiddle on IE and FF supports `object` and `embed` tags for `svg`. But JSFiddle on Chrome does not display `svg` from `object` and `embed`.

**Example**
[JSFiddle example to demonstrate the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/njpLopot/). This fiddle works fine in FF and IE but does not work in Chrome. I am using Chrome Version **37.0.2062.120**.

**How do I make `embed` tag works for `svg` in 3 major browsers (Chrome,FF,IE) and on `jsfiddle` as well ???**

Comment: Any luck to get this worked on jsfiddle ???

Comment: Please post a jsfiddle that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @ErikDahlström - [her is the fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/njpLopot/)

Comment: Thanks, I've filed http://crbug.com/420983 for this, there should at least be some error message in the console log - also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15234184/iframe-sandbox-is-blocking-embed-object.